# Access next webpage after clicking

Tags: regex, html, powershell, dom

Requirement : After clicking on webpage named in $ie.Navigate below. I Need to access HTML / OuterHTML source of Web-page which opens next.

Ex: When I open https://www.healthkartplus.com/search/all?name=Sporanox (by setting $control = Sporanox), below code simply clicks on first matching link. After link is clicked, I need to access HTML of resulting page.

Update : referred another SO question and learned that we can search appropriate window. Code seems to be working for some scenarios but not for all. For $ie2 I get problem accessing Document property.

```
function getStringMatch
 {
    # Loop through all 2 digit combinations in the $path directory
    foreach ($control In $controls)
    {
        $ie = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application
        $ie.visible = $true
        $site = $ie.Navigate("https://www.healthkartplus.com/search/all?name=$control")
        $ie.ReadyState

        while ($ie.Busy -and $ie.ReadyState -ne 4){ sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

        $link = $null
        $link = $ie.Document.get_links() | where-object {$_.innerText -eq "$control"}
        $link.click()

        while ($ie.Busy -and $ie.ReadyState -ne 4){ sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

       $ie2 = (New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application').Windows() | ? {
       $_.Name -eq 'Windows Internet Explorer' -and $_.LocationName -match "^$control"
       }

        # NEED outerHTML of new page. CURRENTLY it is working for some.

        $ie.Document.body.outerHTML > d:\med$control.txt
    }
}

$controls = "Sporanox"

getStringMatch
```

Comment: In the page you first navigate to you have two Sporanox links, you want the HTML of both targets? just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is when you look for the links in the first page.
The link innerText is not equal to $control, it contains $control i.e. innerText is "Sporanox (100mg)".

The following might help:

```
$link = $ie.Document.get_links() | where-object {if ($_.innerText){$_.innerText.contains($control)}}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the complete code I'm using:

```
function getStringMatch
{
    # Loop through all 2 digit combinations in the $path directory
    foreach ($control In $controls)  
    {
        $ie = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application
        $ie.visible = $true
        $site = $ie.Navigate("https://www.healthkartplus.com/search/all?name=$control")
        $ie.ReadyState

        while ($ie.Busy -and $ie.ReadyState -ne 4){ sleep -Milliseconds 100 }   

        $link = $null
        $link = $ie.Document.get_links() | where-object {if ($_.innerText){$_.innerText.contains($control)}}
        $link.click()

        while ($ie.Busy)
        { 
            sleep -Milliseconds 100 
        }

        # NEED outerHTML of new page. CURRENTLY it is working for some.

        $ie.Document.body.outerHTML > d:\med$control.txt
    }
}

$controls = "Sporanox"

getStringMatch
```

Comment: Yes, when the found $link is clicked, the OuterHTML contains the new page. I can see in the file created that "Check Availability" is there as well as "Rs. 304.50 for 1 Strip(s) (4 Capsule each)" which were not in the first page.

Comment: Can you please confirm once. It is confusing because I still see old outerHTML page without "Check Availability" thing.

Comment: Yes it's a matter of time, it saves before the page is loaded, I'm looking into it.

Comment: I think I found the issue. The While loop never worked.

Comment: Which is really weird: `while ($ie.Busy -and $ie.ReadyState -ne 4){ sleep -Milliseconds 100 }` This is valid to me, however it didn't work. While this `while ($ie.Busy -ne $false)
        { 
            sleep -Milliseconds 100 
        }` works

Comment: Thanks for this. I do not think I could have solved it anytime in my life !   Though I am trying to be greedy here - I am facing one more problem. Some of medicine names are having special charatcers like "%" and "&" and prove to be problem. I am putting it in my next question. Thanks again.